# Blazor WebAssembly: Method Executes on Initial Page Load but Not on Button Click (Same-Port Backend)

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm developing a Blazor WebAssembly application which includes a backend API hosted on the same port. I've configured the backend by adding controllers using AddControllers and MapControllers. I'm encountering an issue where a method (FetchData) in my Blazor app is called and executes successfully during the initial page load, but does not trigger when clicking a Fluent UI button designed to call the same method.

The FetchData method is supposed to make an HTTP GET request to my backend API using HttpClient provided by IHttpClientFactory, and then update a variable (weatherSummary) with the response. This works as expected when the page first loads (OnInitializedAsync calls FetchData and it fetches data correctly). However, when I click the Fluent UI button that should also trigger FetchData, it seems that the method is not being called or executed correctly.

Razor page content:

```
@page "/"
@inject IHttpClientFactory HttpClientFactory

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new Blazor app.

@if (weatherSummary != null)
{
    <p>Weather forecast: @weatherSummary</p>
}

<FluentButton OnClick="FetchData">Fetch Weather Data</FluentButton>

@code {
    private string? weatherSummary;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await FetchData();
    }

    private async Task FetchData()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("FetchData called.");
        var httpClient = HttpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        weatherSummary = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("SampleData");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print($"Weather Data: {weatherSummary}");
    }
}
```

SampleData.cs:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class SampleData : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries =
    [
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    ];

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<string> Get() =>
        Summaries[new Random().Next(Summaries.Length)];
}
```

Note that i also tried making the fetch request in all small letters, and it did not work.

Comment: Please state the version of Blazor you are using? If this is 8.0 as you have no rendermode specified. This does sound like the page is being SSR'd